# Stop navigation WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wknavigationdelegate

This is my situation:

I have a view controller within a WKWebView. This webview starts with a page "A". In this page there are some links (href) and I want that for some of these links must open in the external browser.

For this reason I set the WKWebView delegate:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        if let url = webView.url?.absoluteString
        {

                if(self.isExternalURL(url))
                {
                    let urlT = URL(string: url)!
                    decisionHandler(.cancel)
                    UIApplication.shared.open(urlT, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
                else
                {
                    decisionHandler(.allow)
                }
         }
         else
         {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
         }
}

private func isExternalURL(url:String) -> Bool
{
    //......check link
}
```

My problem is that if I select an external link the external browser opens, but the webview does not remain on page A, but it also loads the external link while I would like it to remain on page A.

I dont know why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `navigationAction.request.url` instead of `webView.url`

- `webView.url` - Already loaded url
- `navigationAction.request.url` - New url to load

Change

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString
    {
        if self.isExternalURL(url)
        {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Comment: getting same url multiple times, how can cancel req after getting url first time

Comment: thsi function called multiple time how can i handle this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use  `webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)`

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        if let url = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString
        {
            if self.isExternalURL(url)
            {
               webView.stopLoading()
                UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }

        }

    }
```